# Find standalone percentage (%) from the input string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find all of the standalone "%" on a single line.

Example:

"Some Text % %%" //1 match

"Some more Text %%% % %"  //2 matches

"Even more text about %% % % %%" //2 matches

"Even more text about %% % %%" //1 match

after alot of reading on regex and tries i managed to get opposite of what i need -> [Regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/JMmu0H/4).

Even `%{1}` didn't do the trick. It just finds all of the percentages.

How can i achieve my desired goal from regex? Thanks.

Comment: Use `(?<!%)%(?!%)`

Comment: It does work by matching only standalone `%`: https://regex101.com/r/JMmu0H/5

Comment: add it as an answer with detail explanation of each character so that i and every other needy person can understand and i will accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: yes it does. I missed the starting bracket. Thank you bro.

Comment: If the percentage sign can not be surrounded by other chars use `(?<!\S)%(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/IBGOBT/1

Comment: If you need to match only standalone symbols and ignore the % symbol which are embedded in the words like We%lcome. You can use (?<= )%(?= )|^%(?= )|(?<= )%\z     https://regex101.com/r/cTPMXT/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

To match standalone `%`, you may use a negative lookbehind condition and a negative lookahead condition:

```
(?<!%)%(?!%)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMmu0H/5)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!%)`: negative lookbehind condition to assert we don't have `%` at previous position
- `%`: Match a `%`
- `(?!%)`: negative lookahead condition to assert we don't have `%` at next position

Comment: if there is % symbol in between the word, it will count that % as well. Like Wel%come

Comment: As per OP's requirement it has to match any `%` that is not surrounded by `%`s on either side.